# OSX Maverick Java version's mess

Tags: mac-osx, java

I have installed from the Oracle website, the latest version of Java needed to run Cassandra.

Unfortunately, I still get the error message : 
"Cassandra 2.0 and later require Java 7u25 or later."

After looking around, here's what I got :

```
$ java -version 
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

If I open the Java configuration panel, here's what I get : "Java 8 Update 25"

UPDATE

```
$ls /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
1.6.0.jdk
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I think that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202516/after-upgrading-to-java8-javac-still-shows-1-7 may be of help

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist : Thanks you for the answer, but unfortunately, this answer doesn't help, since apparently at the normal path I should find jdk1.8, it doesn't appear...

Comment: @Sven: configuring Java on a server for server based activity, is relevant to serverfault, doesn't it ?

Comment: I wouldn't consider MacOS X a viable server OS anymore, because of issues like you describe and, more importantly, the lack of any server class hardware to run the OS. Except maybe the "Server.app" stuff for very small workgroups, I would always recommend to use something else for doing real work. Due to this, I interpreted the question in a dev system/proof of concept way. Are you trying to use it for production use?

Comment: Yeah Unfortunately, I did not choose the server I'm working on. It is a macminis' farm... their choices not mine, but that should not prevent me from getting help on serverfault, don't you think ?

Comment: @Sven: want a peek ? http://hpics.li/998fe0e

Comment: Looks interesting. They did a good job hiding the cables.

Comment: @TheSquad Are you sure you don't need the JDK version 7? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Comment: @dean: instaling from the link you gave me have done the trick... Thank you... create the answer, and I'll accept it !

Comment: @TheSquad great, glad to help...just ran across as similar problem myself while trying to install an open source jabber server on OS X server. Answer submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the JDK Version 7 from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html